# Return WP avatar inside a function

Tags: avatar

I am trying to override a plugin's built in avatar with the default WP avatar. The plugin's filter is this:

```
add_filter( "idea_push_change_user_image", "idea_push_change_user_image_callback", 10, 1 );

function idea_push_change_user_image_callback( $userId ) 
{
  return "https://cdn.britannica.com/55/174255-004-9A4971E9.jpg";
}
```

I tried replacing that with 'get_avatar' but it ends up with a broken jpg image

```
add_filter( "idea_push_change_user_image", "idea_push_change_user_image_callback", 10, 1 );

function idea_push_change_user_image_callback( $userId ) 
{
  return get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 );
}
```

Any ideas how to fix, thanks

UPDATE:

Thanks for answers, this has helped. Turns out I needed to pull another plugins (Ultimate Member) avatar not the default:

```
add_filter( "idea_push_change_user_image", "idea_push_change_user_image_callback", 10, 1 );

function idea_push_change_user_image_callback( $userId )
{
  return um_get_user_avatar_url();
}
```

What's weird is it's only working/visible to the logged in user, not visible to anyone else.

Comment: The return value of get_avatar is an img tag, not just the url, which as it seems the plugin needs. Try get_avatar_url instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below line your code

```
return get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 );
```

to

```
return get_avatar_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) is probably unnecessary when $userId is one of the parameters being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixed it. Had to get the UM avatar:

```
add_filter( "idea_push_change_user_image", 
  "idea_push_change_user_image_callback", 10, 1 ); 
function 
  idea_push_change_user_image_callback( $userId ) 
{ return um_get_user_avatar_url($userId ); }
```